# How to create a vector of tuples in C++?

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdtuple

There is a generator which generates a tuple of 16 integers with each iteration. I want to add these tuples into a vector. While creating the vector I have to write `std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, .... 16 times>>`. Is there another way to create a vector of these tuples.

Code to test for the case of tuples containing 5 integers:

```
#include "cppitertools/itertools.hpp"
#include <iostream> 
#include <tuple>
#include <vector> 

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1{0, 1};
    std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int, int, int>> states;

    for (auto&& i : iter::product<5>(v1)) 
    {
        states.push_back(i);
    }

    auto size = states.size();
    std::cout << size << std::endl;

}
```

I'm using [cppiterator](https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools#product)

Comment: I don't know what that tool is and what interfaces it offers, but it sounds like an `std::array` of 16 ints would be a better solution than a tuple of 16 ints.

Comment: So you don't want to write `int, ` 16 times?

Comment: @songyuanyao I want to use this code as a part of experiments where the numbers vary from 4 to 100. So writing `int, ` 100 times is not scalable.

Comment: @papabiceps What's the return type of `iter::product<5>(v1)`?

Comment: If the numbers vary, use a vector instead. So a vector of vectors. If they vary only at compile time, you can put that number into a constexpr and still use `std::array`.

Comment: Why do you require this new vector? `iter::product` already seems to return some collection that you can iterate over. Depending on the return type of `iter::product` you could do smth. like `std::vector { iter::product<5>(v1).begin(), iter::product<5>(v1).end() }` if you're using C++17

Comment: @StefanGroth it looks like `iter::product` is returning a range of `std::tuple<int&, int&, int&, int&, int&>`s

Comment: It is returning a tuple of ints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<size_t Remaining, typename Type,typename ... Args>
struct make_tuple_n_impl{
    using type=typename make_tuple_n_impl<Remaining-1,Type,Type,Args...>::type;
};

template<typename T,typename ... Args>
struct make_tuple_n_impl<0,T,Args...>{
    using type=std::tuple<Args...>;
};

template<size_t Count,typename Type>
using tuple_of=typename make_tuple_n_impl<Count,Type>::type;
```

Then `tuple_of<5,int>` is `std::tuple<int,int,int,int,int>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just fiddle the tuple type that `iter::product` creates

```
#include "cppitertools/itertools.hpp"
#include <iostream> 
#include <tuple>
#include <vector> 

template <typename>
struct remove_tuple_reference;

template <typename... Ts>
struct remove_tuple_reference<std::tuple<Ts...>> {
    using type = std::tuple<std::remove_reference_t<Ts>...>;
};

template <typename T>
using remove_tuple_reference_t = typename remove_tuple_reference<T>::type;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1{0, 1};
    using tup = remove_tuple_reference_t<decltype(iter::product<5>(v1).begin())::value_type>;
    std::vector<tup> states;

    for (auto&& i : iter::product<5>(v1)) 
    {
        states.push_back(i);
    }

    auto size = states.size();
    std::cout << size << std::endl;

}
```